F = 56 - X / (Y * 17) in Assembly Emu8086
I'm trying to solve this expression
F = 56 - X / (Y * 17)

in Assembly (Emu8086)
X, Y are variables.
I'm a complete beginner and I have done this (but probably not correct):
Mov bx, 56      ;  BХ = 56   
Mov ax, Y       ;  AX = Y
Mov cx, 17      ;  CX = 17
Mul cx          ;  DX:AX = AX * CX          (Y * 17)
Xor dx, dx      ;  set DX to zero  ->  AX = (Y * 17)
Mov cx, ax      ;  CX = (Y * 17)
Mov ax, X       ;  AX = X

Div cx          ;  AX / CX         -> AL = X / (Y * 17)
                ;                     AH - remainder

;Add bx, ?  (I can't add bx and al) How to solve this issue?
 

What is going to be next?

Divide the calculation into steps, track what is in which register after each step, be aware what the instructions do. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ can help with the last point.

Note: I think your current code will compute 56*Y/17 in AX. See the above link for details about mul and div. I don't see an attempt at tackling the subtraction in your formula.

Carefully reread the descriptions of the mul and div instructions, including where their inputs come from and where their results go. Your comments do not match what the instructions actually do.

@teapot418, thank you very much!
It seems like I start to understand sth.
I have changed my code (see above, in the question)
But can I ask you one thing?
Now I need to say: ax = X, then delete it by Y * 17.
But what does DX:AX mean?
Can I say that Y * 17 = CX or not?
What shoul I do next?
Hope for help

@NateEldredge, thank you very much! It seems like I start to understand sth. I have changed my code (see above, in the question) But can I ask you one thing? Now I need to say: ax = X, then delete it by Y * 17. But what does DX:AX mean? Can I say that Y * 17 = CX or not? What shoul I do next? Hope for help

MUL returns a 32-bit result, with the low 16 bits in AX and the high bits in DX. If you know that the result fits in 16 bits (it's between 0 and 65535) then you can just look at AX and ignore DX (it would be 0). So after MUL, the value of Y*17 is in AX.

The instruction MUL CX does not put the result in CX. The explicit operand to MUL is input only, so CX would not be modified at all; after the instruction it still contains 17.

So to set up for the next step, the division, you need the value of X in AX, 0 in DX, and the result of 17*Y in some other register. Think about how to get there.

@NateEldredge, Thank you for such a clear explanation!
But Y is a variable, so I don't know whether 0 in DX or not.
What should I do in this case?

If you need DX to be zero, then make it so (xor dx, dx).

@teapot418, Thank you!

If you have to handle the case where 17Y > 65535 then it will take some more work. But in that case, since X is also 16 bits, the result of X/(Y17) would be 0 (unsigned integer division truncates).

@NateEldredge, Thank you for your help!

@NateEldredge,  thousand of appologies, but I have a trouble with DIV and ADD (something is wrong with DIV) (see above)
Would appreciate if you could help me again

@teapot418, thousand of appologies, but I have a trouble with DIV and ADD (something is wrong with DIV) (see above) Would appreciate if you could help me again

The 16-bit DIV CX produces a 16-bit quotient in AX, not AL. (You might be confusing it with the 8-bit form, when you specify an 8-bit divisor like DIV CH). So now you can just SUB BX, AX.

@NateEldredge, thank you! I understand now!


I'm trying to solve this expression F = 56 - X / (Y * 17)

The brackets around (Y * 17) are the most important here. Without them you'd first have to divide X by Y, and then multiply that by 17.
You seem already assuming both X and Y are word-sized unsigned variables.
For a word-sized multiplication one of the operands is mandatory the AX register. Just load the constant (17) in AX and then mul by the memory operand. This will leave a 32-bit product in DX:AX, and let's assume the product is in the 16-bit range [0,65535]:
mov  ax, 17
mul  Y         ; -> DX:AX is product, assuming DX=0 (*)

For the word-sized division that now has to follow, the dividend is mandatory in the DX:AX register pair, so we need to move the product Y * 17 elsewhere:
mov  bx, ax
mov  ax, X     ; Still assuming DX=0, so this shaves off `xor dx, dx`
div  bx        ; -> AX is quotient, DX is remainder

Most of the time we will want to deliver our result in AX, so we could move the previous quotient elsewhere and then finally do the subtraction as in mov bx, ax mov ax, 56 sub ax, bx, but since 56 - Q is equal to 56 + -Q is equal to -Q + 56, we can write instead:
neg  ax
add  ax, 56


An alternative that doesn't need to assume about the product being in the 16-bit range:
Because 56 - X / (Y * 17) is equal to 56 - X / Y / 17 and following algebraic rules (precedence and left-to-right):
xor  dx, dx    ; X / Y
mov  ax, X
div  Y         ; -> AX is quotient, DX is remainder

xor  dx, dx    ; (X / Y) / 17
mov  bx, 17
div  bx        ; -> AX is quotient, DX is remainder

neg  ax        ; 56 - ((X / Y) / 17)
add  ax, 56


Thank you very much for your help and clear explanation!
